# too many points in Julia plots

Tags: plot, julia

Suppose I have `x=1:100000001` and `y = 1:10000000`. Empirically (using GR, at least), `plot(x, y)` crashes every time, presumably because it wants to loving massage every point, of which there are many. Now, clearly, we don't have ten million by ten million resolution, and so what we really want is to plot every 1000th (or something) pair. It seems one has to do this by hand. Is this true, or is there some package that does the right thing (by the way, this is not really Julia specific - it seems to be a problem with every plotting package I have seen).

Comment: In Jupyter or in the GUIs? If it's Jupyter, then with Plots.jl you can use `gr(fmt=:png)` to make it output a png instead of an SVG and that helps quite a bit.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I used Jupyter. I had assumed using a png would only help after the smoke had cleared (by which time it was too late) but I will try. As for GUIs, which ones? Juno, or is there some others?

Comment: SVGs are the issue since they have to store every point in the notebook. If you look at the notebook code you'll see what I mean. If you use a PNG, it stores the raster image and then just adds the link into the notebook: that's much much much smaller. For GUIs [I use Juno to develop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5iGVkI7XOI)